# Javascript Formula for .html() Equivalent

Tags: javascript, php

Just a thought, other than Document.Write() , I also heard that .html() is a good and efficient way to load both script and html tags unto the Page. But is there a better way to use innerHTML in a manner similar to .html of JQuery, I dont want to use JQuery Plugins since they consume the Page capacity, and also want to create my own Javascript Plugin via basic Javascript initiation. :)

Comment: actually jQuery's `.html` uses `innerHTML` property behind the scenes. you should set the `innerHTML` of your target container even if it contains scripts

Comment: But it doesnt execute scripts as expected, Ive been wandering around the internet searching for solutions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.html() method uses the browser's innerHTML property`So as @Manish said in the comment  you would need to add the `innerHTML` of your target container.

A sample example can be found from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: You mean, add the Script Tags into the Target Container and execute a script recreation into it and output using innerHTML?

Comment: With an eval in it? :)

Comment: I mean, to evaluate executable scripts without their tags in it.

Comment: You have to use eval() to execute any script that you've inserted as DOM text.